# .Net Regular Expression match at least one of multiple keywords

Tags: .net, regex

Im using an application (AstroGrep) that uses .Net Regular Expression to search for files (in the names and contents). I have a list of keywords that I need to search for. Im new to Regular Expressions (shortened RegEx?) But have tried to find something that would work. Lets say my keywords are:

1. apples
2. oranges
3. bananas
4. grapes

<s>I tried 
`apples|oranges|bananas|grapes`
but that did not work. It actually return zero results even though I had created some dummy files to test this search. If I search the words individually it will find the files.</s>
I am not concerned about matching whole words only, but I would need it to be NOT case sensitive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks
~Mike

**EDIT** Looks like I can't read... I didn't click the checkbox to indicate that I was using a regular expression.

the above regex works... sort of. It looks like it will only find files that have one word or the other, and files that contain both it does not find.

What expression would I use to search for files that may contain any of the keywords and some that may contain multiple keywords?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(?i)(apples|oranges|bananas|grapes)
```

`(?i)`  = Case Insesitivity

`(apples|oranges|bananas|grapes)` =(word OR word OR word OR word)

Perhaps your brackets were missing?

Comment: This did work, sort of, it seems to find files with one of the keywords but it does not seem to find files that contain two or more of the keywords.

Comment: So it only matched files with one of the keywords? If a file had Bananas and Apples(Something i never thought id say:-)) it wouldnt match?

Comment: You are correct. IF a file contain more than one of the keywords it did not 'find' that one.

Comment: Are you using `Regex.Matches`? If more than one match is found, you'll have to iterate over the matches to get every single one. When you're only interested in whether a text contains at least one of the keywords (but it doesn't matter which one or where they occur), `Regex.IsMatch` is your friend.

Comment: @MariusSchulz Marius, unfortunately I did not create the program so I am unsure how it was programmed. I might need to find another tool.

Comment: @MikeFletcher85 Purely out of interest what happens if you keep the above regex but add the following '*(apples|oranges|bananas|grapes)' Does this match files with two occurrences?

Comment: @Srb1313711 `(apples|oranges|bananas|grapes)'` returned nothing. `(apples|oranges|bananas|grapes)'*` Returned just the files where only one keyword was present.

Comment: If your searching files try http://download.cnet.com/SearchMyFiles/3000-2248_4-10909575.html its what I use you can specify multiple locations and multiple values to look for in these locations, or do you specifically want to use regex?